# Creating hierarchy in SQL Table

Tags: sql, recursion, hierarchy

I'm currently trying to build a parent-child relationship on a table that does not contain this information.

it is a list of financial account numbers and a corresponding type, thats about it.

Now there is a logic to this though, header accounts group profitAndLoss accounts with a total at the end. headers can be nested and totals can be as well forming the parent child structure within this logic is my current task

I have gotten as far as to rank the changes in that should result in a switch in the parent account. But I'm a bit stuck at building my recursive query to move all the way to my desired output.

currently I'm at this level (Simplified example)

```
WITH accounts AS (
    SELECT 
        accountNumber, accountType

    FROM (VALUES
        (1000, 'heading'),
        (1001, 'heading'),
        (1010, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1020, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1021, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1025, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1099, 'totalFrom'),
        (1300, 'heading'),
        (1310, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1320, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1321, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1399, 'totalFrom'),
        (2000, 'totalFrom'),
        (2200, 'heading'),
        (2210, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (2211, 'profitAndLoss')
    ) AS t(accountNumber, accountType)
),

rankedAccounts AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        COALESCE(
            CASE WHEN LAG(accountNumber) OVER(ORDER BY accountNumber) IS NULL THEN 0 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType, 2) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IS NULL THEN 1 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('heading', 'headingStart') THEN 0 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('profitAndLoss', 'status') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('heading', 'headingStart') THEN 1 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') AND LAG(accountType, 2) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') THEN 0 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') AND LAG(accountType, 2) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('profitAndLoss', 'status') THEN -1 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') THEN -1 END,
            0
        ) Rank

    FROM
        accounts
),

sumRank AS (
    SELECT 
        accountNumber,
        accountType,
        SUM(Rank) OVER (ORDER BY rankedAccounts.accountNumber) sumRank
    
    FROM rankedAccounts
)

SELECT
    *

FROM
    sumRank
```

The resulting data from this query is a follows

[image]

my desired output would look like this

[image]

I can do this easily in python using a very simple loop, but I cannot wrap my head around it in T-SQL

```
accountDictList = [
    {'accountNumber': 1000, 'accountType':'heading', 'sumRank':0},
    {'accountNumber': 1001, 'accountType':'heading', 'sumRank':1},
    {'accountNumber': 1010, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1020, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1021, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1025, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1099, 'accountType':'totalFrom', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1300, 'accountType':'heading', 'sumRank':1},
    {'accountNumber': 1310, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1320, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1321, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 1399, 'accountType':'totalFrom', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 2000, 'accountType':'totalFrom', 'sumRank':1},
    {'accountNumber': 2200, 'accountType':'heading', 'sumRank':1},
    {'accountNumber': 2210, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
    {'accountNumber': 2211, 'accountType':'profitAndLoss', 'sumRank':2},
]

for i, account in enumerate(accountDictList):
    try:
        if i == 0:
            parent = None
        elif account['sumRank'] > accountDictList[i-1]['sumRank']:
            grandparent = parent
            parent = accountDictList[i-1]['accountNumber']
        elif account['sumRank'] < accountDictList[i-1]['sumRank']:
            parent = grandparent
    except:
        parent = parent

    print(account, parent)
```

resulting in the desired output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python you have variables, in sql not, so you need subqueries to get the wanted information

```
WITH accounts AS (
    SELECT 
        accountNumber, accountType

    FROM (VALUES
        (1000, 'heading'),
        (1001, 'heading'),
        (1010, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1020, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1021, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1025, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1099, 'totalFrom'),
        (1300, 'heading'),
        (1310, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1320, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1321, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (1399, 'totalFrom'),
        (2000, 'totalFrom'),
        (2200, 'heading'),
        (2210, 'profitAndLoss'),
        (2211, 'profitAndLoss')
    ) AS t(accountNumber, accountType)
),

rankedAccounts AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        COALESCE(
            CASE WHEN LAG(accountNumber) OVER(ORDER BY accountNumber) IS NULL THEN 0 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType, 2) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IS NULL THEN 1 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('heading', 'headingStart') THEN 0 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('profitAndLoss', 'status') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('heading', 'headingStart') THEN 1 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') AND LAG(accountType, 2) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') THEN 0 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('heading', 'headingStart') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') AND LAG(accountType, 2) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('profitAndLoss', 'status') THEN -1 END,
            CASE WHEN accountType IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') AND LAG(accountType) OVER (ORDER BY accountNumber) IN ('totalFrom', 'sumInterval') THEN -1 END,
            0
        ) Rank

    FROM
        accounts
),

sumRank AS (
    SELECT 
        accountNumber,
        accountType,
        SUM(Rank) OVER (ORDER BY rankedAccounts.accountNumber) sumRank
    
    FROM rankedAccounts
)

SELECT
    *,
 CASE WHEN sumrank = 0 then NULL
  WHEN sumrank = 1 THEN ( SELECT accountNumber FROM sumRank WHERE sumRank = 0)
  ELSE ( SELECT accountNumber FROM sumRank WHERE sumRank = 1 AND accountNumber < s1.accountNumber ORDER BY accountnumber DESC LIMIT 1)
  END parent
FROM
    sumRank s1
```

| accountnumber | accounttype | sumrank | parent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | heading | 0 | *null* |
| 1001 | heading | 1 | 1000 |
| 1010 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 1001 |
| 1020 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 1001 |
| 1021 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 1001 |
| 1025 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 1001 |
| 1099 | totalFrom | 2 | 1001 |
| 1300 | heading | 1 | 1000 |
| 1310 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 1300 |
| 1320 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 1300 |
| 1321 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 1300 |
| 1399 | totalFrom | 2 | 1300 |
| 2000 | totalFrom | 1 | 1000 |
| 2200 | heading | 1 | 1000 |
| 2210 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 2200 |
| 2211 | profitAndLoss | 2 | 2200 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yqFe-68b)

Comment: Thank's this helped me out :) had to tweak it a bit for SQL Server (Forgot to mention that it is T-SQL) but not a big thing (TOP(1) in stead of LIMIT 1)